# How to remove or replace all console.log in Angular SSR

Tags: node.js, angular

I've built an angular project with CLI. when I run the project It shows all `console.log` that I used in development mode. Then I googled and found a solution. Replaced with empty function in the production mode by adding two lines of code in `main.ts` file:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  if (window) {
    window.console.log = window.console.warn = window.console.info = window.console.debug = function () {/* no log */ };
  }
}
```

It helps me to get rid out of that problem in production mode and saves a lot of time of removing all `console.log` lines manually. So, I added those lines in `main.server.ts` file also to solve the problem in `SSR`.

But, the problem is when I build with **angular SSR** and run the project it returns errors:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.K011 (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:176367)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:295)
    at Object.0 (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:5525)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:295)
    at +JNS (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:1624)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\10MS\10-minute-school-3.0\dist\server\main.js:1:1669)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
```

I understand the problem that there is no global `window` variable in nodejs. But, I need to remove all `console.log` lines. How can I able to remove all `console.log` lines in `SSR` build.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in the **main.ts** file, you can override the console methods (log, warn, error, etc) in the **app.module.ts** file just before the app is initialized. This can be done using the `APP_INITIALIZER` injector token that allows you run some custom initialization logic needed for your app.

The `PLATFORM_ID` is another injector token that is provided by the Angular once the platform is initialized (platform can be server, browser or web worker) and it is available before application initialization. Using this token we can determine the platform using the `isPlatformBrowser(platformId)` method which returns `true` if the platform is a browser.

We can combine the above 2 strategies to override the console methods as below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {
  NgModule,
  Injector,
  APP_INITIALIZER,
  PLATFORM_ID
} from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from "@angular/common";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
...

/**
 * Factory method to override the console methods
 * during app initialization
 */
function silenceConsoleMethods(injector: Injector) {
  return () => {
    const platformId = injector.get(PLATFORM_ID);
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId) && environment.production) {
      window.console.log = window.console.debug = window.console.warn = window.console.error = () => {};
    } else if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
      console.log = console.debug = console.warn = console.error = () => {};
    }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: silenceConsoleMethods,
      deps: [Injector],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can find a working version of the above example in Stackbliz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/silence-console-methods). To demonstrate the solution works, I have overriden all console logging methods except error to show the error messages on console.

**P.S:**

You can use `isPlatformServer(platformId)` to determine if the platform is server and perform any initialization logic related to server side rendering.

**Edit:**

Updated `silenceConsoleMethods()` in the **app.module.ts** file to override the console object when the app is rendered using Nodejs runtime. Now you should not face any problem when the app is rendered on server side.

Comment: Suppose if I want to replace all console.log in server side rendering mode is this code will work for that. Since there is no window in nodejs

Comment: @AnwarulIslam You are right. Nodejs does not have a window object, but it has a `console` object which works similar to `window.console` object. I have updated my answer to override the console objects if the platform is server.